# Retrieving Specific information from multiple xml files and output to a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

The scenario is that I have a TV listings html page, which contains a table of TV program titles, populated by XML data. I want the user to be able to click on the program title and to be given a description of the title, which also comes from the same XML file.

I previously tried using `.dialog` but I could not get this to work. I am now opening a separate, smaller window which gives the title for one program and one program only. This is not what I want, I would like all titles to link to their own descriptions.

This is the `JavaScript` code that works for one program, (which I would rather have in `jQuery`):

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00533474/workspace/COM554/assignment_2/CR/sky_one.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
//the next 4 lines retrieves the elements title, description and times of the programme from the sky one xml file
title=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
desc=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("desc")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
start=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("start")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
end=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("end")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
//formatting with HTML for the output
document.write("<h1>"+title+"</h1>"+"<br><p>Programmme description:</p>"+desc+"<br>"+"<p>Start time:</p>"+start+"-"+end);
```

I think I have to use `.when` and `.then` to use multiple XML files but I am unsure of how to implement this.

Below is my HTML for the small description window:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="js/descriptionGET.js"></script>
</html>
```

The desired output is a description for every program on the channel lists (each XML file is one channel). Any help would be much appreciated. [image: Image of the Output for this JavaScript and HTML code once the user has clicked on a title.]

**EDIT**

I have now been able to implement the `.dialog` feature for an unordred list although I cannot implement is in my actual html page. I am creating a HTML table from XML then trying to implement the `.dialog` feature this is the jQuery I have for the table:

```
//sky one
            sky1p.each(function(k, v) {
                tr.clone().html( td.clone().html( $(this).find('start').text() ) )
                .append( td.clone().html('<div data-xml-id="' + k + '">' + '<div id="tvlistingssky1">' + $(v).find('title').text() + '</div> </div>') )
                .data( 'time', $(this).find('start').text() )
                .appendTo( tbody );
            });
```

This is the jquery for the dialog:

```
 var xml;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      // init dialog
      $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        open: function() {
              $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function() {
                  $('#dialog').dialog('close');
              });
          }
      });

      // load xml doc and append parsed plant names to html document
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00533474/workspace/COM554/assignment_2/CR/sky_one.xml",
      dataType: "xml"
    }).done($('#tvlistingssky1').on('click', 'div', function() { // show dialog on click

    })

      var programme = $(this),
        progId = programme.data('xmlId'),
        title = xml.find('programme').eq(progId).find('title').text(),
        description = xml.find('programme').eq(progId).find('desc').text();

      $('#dialog').html('<h1>' + title + '</h1> <br />' + "Description: '" + programme.text() + "' is " + description)
            .dialog('open');

    });

    });
```

If anyone could help as the only thing that shows is the dialog pointer not the actual dialog box, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `.dialog`. I would approach like this:

1. Load and parse XML document (to whom we keep a reference) and append objects to document
2. Attach 'onclick' listener for appended objects, so that we can later query the XML doc for required data
3. Construct jQuery dialog for showing queried data from the XML doc

Something like http://pastebin.com/gYzdpSen for HTML and http://pastebin.com/JRd5mdNT for XML data.

Comment: Thanks for the help @r00m, I have tried implementing this solution and have it working for an ordered list, although I cannot seem to get it working for a div. I used the code: ` sky1p.each(function(k, v) {
                tr.clone().html( td.clone().html( $(this).find('start').text() ) )
                .append( td.clone().html('<div data-xml-id="' + k + '">' + '<div id="tvlistingssky1">' + $(v).find('title').text() + '</div> </div>') )
                .data( 'time', $(this).find('start').text() )
                .appendTo( tbody );
            });` Could you help me out?